# HTML table with qrcode as column; loading issues on tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table with QRcode as one of its column values; I use QRcode.min js library to convert the string to QRcode;

```js
json = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res.d));
// console.log('data ' , json);
$.each(json, function (i, item) {
    // console.log(item.medicine);console.log(item.Medicine);
    if (item.QrImg1 == null) {
        td1 = $('<td>').text(' ');
    } else {
        td1 = $('<td>').qrcode({ width: 100, height: 100, text: item.QrImg1 })
    }
    if (item.QrImg2 == null) {
        td2 = $('<td>').text(' ');
    } else {
        td2 = $('<td>').qrcode({ width: 100, height: 100, text: item.QrImg2 })
    }
    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td   style="width:30%">').text(item.Medicine),
        $('<td>').text(item.BatchCode),
        td1,
        td2
    ).appendTo('#meds');
}
```

This is a pharmacy app, where in all the medicines along with their batch code(as QRCode) is displayed. They will have to do quick filter search on the medicine name so pagination wont help.
The issue is that I have around 6000+ row so while loading it takes time specially on a tablet. Is there some way I can get this loaded faster.

Comment: try implementing my suggestion  then if you stuck or need help  update your code in question then comment on my answer .

Comment: to give you working code pls add json data

Comment: Yes, you could implement server-side processing to reduce client's data set.

Comment: also if your qrcode takes time try rendering table rows without it  then when item selected  invoke  `.qrcode()` on that selected element

Comment: But that will mean alot of interaction with the application for the enduser; need minimal interaction with the appln

Comment: My Json looks like {Medicine: "ZONIZEP 25MG TAB",
BatchCode: "BST1270",
QrImg1: null,
QrImg2: "BST1270"}

Answer (score 0):

if you get the data one time from the server and you do search on client side from table then jquery.DataTables will help you  filter rows https://datatables.net/

it has many options customize the view of table  & functionality like sort /  search / group

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr><th class="site_name">Name</th><th>Url </th><th>Type</th><th>Last modified</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  


$("#example").dataTable({
  "aaData":[
    ["Sitepoint","http://sitepoint.com","Blog","2013-10-15 10:30:00"],
    ["Flippa","http://flippa.com","Marketplace","null"],
    ["99designs","http://99designs.com","Marketplace","null"],
    ["Learnable","http://learnable.com","Online courses","null"],
    ["Rubysource","http://rubysource.com","Blog","2013-01-10 12:00:00"]
  ],
  "aoColumnDefs":[{
        "sTitle":"Site name"
      , "aTargets": [ "site_name" ]
  },{
        "aTargets": [ 1 ]
      , "bSortable": false
      , "mRender": function ( url, type, full )  {
          return  '<a href="'+url+'">' + url + '</a>';
      }
  },{
        "aTargets":[ 3 ]
      , "sType": "date"
      , "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
          return (full[2] == "Blog") 
                    ? new Date(date).toDateString()
                    : "N/A" ;
      }  
  }]
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```